# Why is my Rotation Matrix not working?

Tags: java, vector, rotation

I have various entities in my game that have hit-boxes defined by Vector array's,

one of my entities rotates slowly to follow the player's movements so naturally I need the hit-box to rotate too.

My code results in warped and distorted lines as I draw each vertex to the screen. My entites are 64 x 64 in size so + 32 indicates the center of the object.

```
    public  void rotateVertices(Vector2[] vertices, double angle) {

    double cos = Math.cos(angle);
    double sin = Math.sin(angle);

    for(int i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++){
        Vector2 v = vertices[i];
        vertices[i].x = ((v.x - (x + 32)) * cos - (v.y - (y + 32)) * sin) + (x + 32);
        vertices[i].y = ((v.x - (x + 32)) * sin + (v.y - (y + 32)) * cos) + (y + 32);
    }

}
```

my constructor:

```
    public EnemyTriBall(Handler handler, float x, float y) {
    super(handler, x, y, 3, 6);

    vertices[0] = new Vector2(x + 25, y + 13);
    vertices[1] = new Vector2(x + 64, y + 33);
    vertices[2] = new Vector2(x + 25, y + 53);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
Vector2 v = vertices[i];
```

You don't make a copy of the old vector, you just reference `vectices[i]`. So when you do this:

```
vertices[i].x = ((v.x - (x + 32)) * cos - (v.y - (y + 32)) * sin) + (x + 32);
```

you modify `x` of of the original vector. Then in the next line:

```
vertices[i].y = ((v.x - (x + 32)) * sin + (v.y - (y + 32)) * cos) + (y + 32);
```

You use old `v.y` but new `v.x` which gives you weird results. The easiest fix would be to get `x` and `y` and use them instead:

```
    float vx = vertices[i].x;
    float vy = vertices[i].y;
    vertices[i].x = ((vx - (x + 32)) * cos - (vy - (y + 32)) * sin) + (x + 32);
    vertices[i].y = ((vx - (x + 32)) * sin + (vy - (y + 32)) * cos) + (y + 32);
```

There might be other issues, I did not check the formulas but I'd start with this one.

Comment: I'll try this after work but I imagine this is what has been holding be back, thanks

Comment: My vertices are no longer skewed but they do rotate too much as I'm passing through my rotated vertices every frame, do you know to to fix this?

Comment: @Alex You might have some problems with formulas, it's a bit hard to diagnose it without debugging. I'd write a few unit tests for known inputs and outputs and check what's wrong. This should not be difficult.